# Uploaded via SSH with user root, can't edit files in cPanel

Tags: server, permissions, hosting

I've mistakenly uploaded a full 32GB of files for a new website launch using SSH and the root login, now we can't edit any files in file manager, can't upload images on the website, etc - is there any quick fix rather than having to re upload the entire thing using the domain specific account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to SSH in as the root again and `cd` into the correct user directory (one level up from public_html) and run `chown -R user:user public_html/*`

`user:user` needs to be the username you setup when making adding the domain to the server.

This will then change all of the ownership to the username registered with the domain hosting package.

Comment: Legend. Thank you so much. Saves me many hours of re uploading! Appreciated

Comment: No problem at all. If this answers your question please feel free to upvote and mark as the selected answer. :)